# How to solve when fread is changing values of other integer variables

Tags: c++, fread

I'm having troubles in my college homework, I'm coding in c++ some sorting methods, and this just happened:

```
int nufi = 0, d;
cout << "nufi  value: " << nufi << endl;

d  = fread(&item, sizeof(ItemType), 1, stripes[nStripe].arq);

cout << "nufi value: " << nufi << endl;
```

That was suposed to print:
  nufi value: 0
  nufi value :0
But, instead, is printing:
  nufi value: 0
  nufi value: 541151813

Basically, any integer variable that passes by the fread is being changed;

I have tried to  change variables names, change opened files and every test that I think and the error persist, not always with that value, when I change variables names, the number changes too, only when I remove the fread, the error disappears.

The rest of the code is fine and tested, the file opening, structs, keys, etc.

Anyone have any idea what may be happening?

Comment: "I'm coding in c++" - so why adding C tag then?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: What is `item`? Most likely, it's not big enough to hold what you've read.

Comment: I'm using c tags besause the homework was change a previously code to work with our structs, then we have to keep the c functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting undefined behaviour, and changing variable *names* will not help.  You have a *type* problem, where `item` is clearly not of type `ItemType`.  Thus, `fread` is writing extra bytes onto your stack where other variable storage lives.

Change the call to this:

```
fread( &item, sizeof(item), 1, stripes[nStripe].arq );
```

You have not actually *shown* its type, but I'm willing to bet that it's `ItemType*`.  In which case, you would have a slightly different syntax:

```
fread( item, sizeof(ItemType), 1, stripes[nStripe].arq );
//     ^ Note reference removed because item is a pointer to ItemType.
```

Comment: It looks like he is having a... stack overflow!

Comment: This is not a stack overflow -- it is _memory stomping_.

Comment: Thank you! Thats solve my problem! I was using the struct name to get the size because the original code was using sizeof(float)